# WSO2 InfoRecoverySample web application not displaying CAPTCHA image in browser

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 identity server for identity management for the APIs published on WSO2 API Manager.We have used sample web application(InfoRecoverySample) for recovering account information as suggested in (https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+Sample+Application+for+Identity+Management).This application has been hosted on a different tomcat server instead of on the same server as WSO2 Identity server. How do we specify the trustStore absolute resource path for trustStorePath in cofiguration?

We have copied the wsocarbon.jks from identity server and pasted in the server where InfoRecoverySample is hosted by providing its absolute path, but in browser we are unable to fetch the CAPTCHA image provided by WSO2 Identity server.

Comment: What is the error you see in browser's developer console?

Comment: @Bee:Error is:- Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED